# Struggling with LOBs

Tags: sql, oracle

I am struggling on figuring out how to search in a LOB. I was trying the following but got the ORA-19011: Character string buffer too small, error

```
select * from gtpintr_data.sagadata sa where SA.DATA like '4780471';
```

Comment: Might be unrelated, but shouldn't it be `like '%4780471%'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL LIKE command only works on varchar-type datatypes like VARCHAR2. Oracle has to convert the LOB to a string in order to run your query, so if it cannot fit it into the maximum size for a string it will fail.

You *could* use `DBMS_LOB.INSTR` in a PL/SQL program instead:

http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_lob.htm#ARPLS66715

But that will be slow as you would need to call it for each row in the table.

A better alternative is to add an Oracle Text index on the column and use the CONTAINS operator.

http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CCREF/toc.htm